# What is the best way to change sidebars based on custom taxonomy terms?

Tags: custom-taxonomy, sidebar

I would like to load different right and left sidebars depending on a custom taxonomy term. If there is no term from this custom taxonomy, then just load the default sidebar.php and sidebar-right.php files.

For example, the alternate sidebars would be something like:

- sidebar-carrots.php and sidebar-carrots-right.php
- sidebar-apples.php and sidebar-apples-right.php
- etc.

I know about the Widget Logic plugin, but I want more control and need to load completely different sidebar template files.

I'm sure that I could throw together something messy and functional, but I would like to know what is the best way to set that up.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 options that comes in mind

First use a conditional statement `is_tax('taxonomy-name', 'term name')`.

```
is_tax('fruits', 'apples'){
    get_sidebar('apples');
    get_sidebar('apples-right');
} if is_tax('fruits', 'oranges') {
    get_sidebar('oranges');
    get_sidebar('oranges-right');
}
```

Or, the second option, use a different template file instead.

taxonomy-fruits-apples.php should use

```
    get_sidebar('apples');
    get_sidebar('apples-right');
```

taxonomy-fruits-oranges.php should use

```
    get_sidebar('oranges');
    get_sidebar('oranges-right');
```

Hope this help